# How to set background and border for each Stacked Column Chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a report with multiple tables and one chart of type Stacked Column.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to set background and border for some of the Stacked Columns in the chart based on some data column. Just to be clear, the border and the background i want to be not to the stacked column itself, but the background "rectangle" where the column is drawn.

I found options to set background of the column itself and border ... but that is not what I need.

Any suggestions?

I'm using SQL 2016 Reporting service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of a chart is controlled by the **Chart Area** properties. You should be able to select the Chart Area by clicking on white space within the chart's axis, and adjust it's BackgroundColor properties from there.

If you want to have varying colours on different parts of a single chart area, you can achieve this with **StripLines**. These can be set on the X and/or Y chart axis properties, depending on if you want horizontal or vertical variance.